# Connection error in websocket over amazon ELB

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elb, vert.x

My service resides in a server which has amazon ELB. The client portion communicates with the 
server by vertx eventbus. While trying to connect the server following logs pops out

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://login.com:7070/Notify/287/mxyox3qd/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

My Code at the client side:

```
  eventBus = new EventBus(url);
        eventBus.onopen = function() {
                  // ---------- Do Something ---------------------------------
            });

        }
```

Does ELB listener have something to do with this? can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Load Balancers don't support web sockets. You need to upgrade to the new [Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/) which does support web sockets.